# How to connect from webpage to raspberry pi locally to control solenoid lock

Tags: raspberry-pi

I already have a web app but I want to be able to control the solenoid door lock using my web app. Is there a way to control raspberry pi or send data?

Comment: Is the web app running on the pi?

Comment: no, the web app is running on another pc.

Comment: if the web app, is hitting a web server on the pi, then it ought to be possible to make a web service to let you toggle the door lock.

Comment: how can i do that ? can you please help me?

Comment: I think that kind of help is beyond the scope of what can be done on SO.   I suggest exercising your google-fu

Comment: not that kind of help that i want to do, i mean where do i start if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a simple web socket on the pi that listens to a node on the web app.
(Think of this as performing an HTTP read on a url in a loop, the url points to a bit on the web app, that changes when the button is pressed)

Look into how the web app is hosted and it might be possible to have the button set a bit that the pi can read.

Comment: i have web app running locally in windows 10 and i want to communicate the web app from raspberry pi to control the solenoid lock, any suggestion ?

Comment: How is the web app written/hosted? If you can edit the web app, create a node, that reflects the button value. Like http://localhost:8080/button.html can have the value of 1 or 0 depending on the value of the button, and you can use a library like requests in python to read it using a web-socket and control the solenoid. 
This is easiest way you can do it, and not meant to be scalable or performance intensive.

Comment: thank you for your response, the web app in windows 10 CI php, so i can use a library request in python using web-socket to raspberry pi OS web app to control the solenoid?

Comment: i will try it, and ill get back, Thank you for your suggestion.